# publishing a form and associating calendar items to it fails in office >2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, interop, outlook-addin

I have developed a ms-outlook addin that seems to work at the pc i have developed it.However when the setup project for this add-in is ran in a machine that has a version of ms-office newer that 2010 the two procedures in addin_startup event seem to be ignored as if the cursor never passed through them.The two procedures are used to publish a form and associate the 'extended with the form' appointment with a calendars' default items

here is most of the code in the addin_startup and the full code of the two procedures

```
    // code in start_up
Outlook.MAPIFolder primaryCalendar = (Outlook.MAPIFolder) this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.MAPIFolder personalCalendar = primaryCalendar.Folders.Add(newCalendarName,Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.MAPIFolder setcalendar = primaryCalendar.Folders[newCalendarName];
PublishFormToPersonalFormsLibrary(setcalendar,outlookformpathandfilename,  registryname, registryname, registryname, registryname + "version 1.0.0.1", "1.0.0.1", Application);
SetFolderDefaultForm_forappointments(setcalendar, "IPM.Appointment." + registryname, newCalendarName);


// first procedure
public void PublishFormToPersonalFormsLibrary(Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarfolder,string oftFilePath, string messageClass, string name, string displayName, string description, string version, Outlook.Application  application)
{
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

string existingVersion = "";

// try to create an existing Instance of the Form to check the current installed Version
try
{
    // create atemplatefolder object
    Outlook.MAPIFolder templateFolder = application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);

    // we add our new object here
    object existingItem = templateFolder.Items.Add(messageClass); 

    // did we installed the form
    if (existingItem != null)
    {
        // yes, we did it before
        // get the formdescription with latebinding
        Type existingItemType = existingItem.GetType();
        Outlook.FormDescription existingFormDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)existingItemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, existingItem, null);

        // get the installed version
        existingVersion = existingFormDescription.Version;

        // discard the temporary item
        object[] args = { Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard };  
        existingItemType.InvokeMember("Close", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod , null, existingItem, args);
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{

}

// if the existing Version is equal, no need for publishing the form
if (version == existingVersion) return;

// check, if the templatefile exists
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(oftFilePath)) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Form template could not be found!", oftFilePath);

// create the item from TemplateFile
object item = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(oftFilePath, missing);

// get the FormDescription Property using LateBinding
Type itemType = item.GetType();
Outlook.FormDescription formDescription = (Outlook.FormDescription)itemType.InvokeMember("FormDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null);

// Apply some Parameters to the Formdescription
formDescription.Name = name;
formDescription.DisplayName = displayName;
formDescription.Category = "uncategorized";
formDescription.Comment = description;
formDescription.Version = version;

// Publish Form to Personal Froms Library
//formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olPersonalRegistry );
formDescription.PublishForm(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFormRegistry.olFolderRegistry , calendarfolder);
```

}

```
//and also second procedure

void SetFolderDefaultForm_forappointments(Outlook.MAPIFolder fld , string msgClass, string displayname ){
    Outlook.PropertyAccessor objPA = fld.PropertyAccessor;
string strBaseType ;
string strMsg ;
int intLoc ;
bool blnBadForm; 
int i ;
string PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS = 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E5001E";
string PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME = 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x36E6001E";

string[] arrSchema = { PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME };
string[]arrValues ={msgClass, displayname};
string[] arrErrors;
try{
     objPA = fld.PropertyAccessor;
     objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS, msgClass);
     objPA.SetProperty(PR_DEF_POST_DISPLAYNAME, displayname);

  //  arrErrors = objPA.SetProperties(arrSchema, arrValues);
    }
catch (SystemException sex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is catch with system exception : {0}", sex.ToString());
    }


}
```

Any idea on how to **upgrade** my add-in in order to have it ran on office 2013 and 2016.What if i try to find a c# 2016 addin project? Is this available for vsto 2010? Or else, does anybody know about what's new in ms-outlook 2013,2016 that may cause the setup not to install the addin,specifically the two procedures?

Comment: Can you verify that your add-in even loads? I assume you mean the ThisAddIn_Startup event isn't firing, and that events contains the calls to these two procedures?